# input type=file doesn't come in request after submiting

Tags: html, django, form-submit

I want to save a form using django modelForm. Everything goes right and when I use "inspect elements" and check network -> headers, each field of form has taken the value from html, but there is no sign of image. (set in input type=file).

Please help me on this problem. I'm really stuck.

here is the form data (taken from inspect element):

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken:bUrPwYEVRqpjLJCPuZysUWsWQUMUNQ4r
name:baaz
category:4
price:100
// no signs of image input :(
```

and a part of my template:

```
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form.name }}
       {{ form.category }}
       {{ form.price }}
       <p>
       Add image:  {{ form.image }}
       </p>
       <input type="file" name="p_image" />
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Have you checked your media url in the settings.py file?  Are you getting any errors or is it simply just failing silently?

Comment: @chawk: media url is okey and i've served media file's like images earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The inspector doesn't show the POST files ok. But in django side (in viesw.py usually) you can access to the file with request.FILE["p_image"]